# How do you keep full-window images & elements proportional as the browser window changes?

Tags: css, scaling

I'm trying to find out ways to keep images, type and other graphic elements that fill a browser window to maintain their proportion and relationships to one another while continuing to fill the window while that window is resized.

To see what I mean, please take a look at the following examples:

Example 1:
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/26/magazine/how-fake-news-turned-a-small-town-upside-down.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fmagazine&action=click&contentCollection=magazine&region=stream&module=stream_unit&version=latest&contentPlacement=1&pgtype=sectionfront

Example 2:
https://www.nytimes.com/2017/09/28/magazine/here-comes-the-closer-in-the-seventh-inning.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fmagazine&action=click&contentCollection=magazine&region=rank&module=package&version=highlights&contentPlacement=6&pgtype=sectionfront

Note how the photo in each, especially in Example 1, is not stretched or squeezed out of its natural shape. Also note how either the full width or the full height of the image is always shown no matter what size the browser window is. Further, the type (headline and intro copy) remains anchored to the bottom left and remains the same size.

How can I achieve this effect?

Additionally, I would like to know how to set the page up so that large image and the graphics that accompany it, change every few seconds.

I would prefer to do this is CSS, but also welcome HTML and other solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: As i can see in source code, this is done by javascript which calculates its height and its width everytime you do a resize update.

Comment: Dorvalla, would you be able to provide me the javascript code that would be used. Sorry, I’m still very inexperienced at coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `background-size: contain;`

In contrast to `background-size: cover;` it does not ensure the background image covers the whole container, instead the background image gets resized so that the height AND the width are the same or smaller than the size of the container.

**Example for contain:**

```css
textarea {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

**Example for cover:**

```css
textarea {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Sidenote: *I intentionally used textareas for the examples, because they can easily be resized in the bottom right corner for testing*

Comment: This addresses the issue, but not completely. Using this code—and substituting 100% for exact pixel measurements, as 3Demon suggested—the image does scale with the browser window and does so proportionately. However, it does not always fill the window while remaining proportional. It is still possible to open the window such that and see areas that are not covered by the image.

Comment: Please look at the linked examples in my original post and see how the images behave as you change the shape of the browser window. The image can appear partially cropped on two sides; say, horizontally. But the other dimension is entirely (or nearly entirely) visible.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give width in % for this kind of effect. Don't specify the height and width for the image in pixels. You will have to use '%' for varying the image width ( with proportionate height ) with the screen size or browser size.

If you wish to provide height and width in pixels then you will have to use media queries in CSS to specify height and width for varying screen sizes.